# How can I open a select options on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select option that is working nicely on click.
Now, I want that select option will be open when mouse is on hover on that select option.

my html is:

```
 <select name="select" id="inputselect" class="form-control">
  <?php
    $i=1;
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){ ?>
    <option value="<?=$i?>">option_<?=$i?></option>
    <?php    }
    ?>
  </select>

  // script will be like this
  $('#inputselect').mouseover(function(event){
     // code for open the select option on mouse hober
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `$('#inputselect').trigger('mousedown')`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I am new in this platform, can you please give me the full script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below snippet.Let me know in comments if you have any qns.

```js
$('select').hover(function() {

  $(this).attr('size', $('option').length);
}, function() {

  $(this).attr('size', 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>first</option>
  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this one is working :)
thank you

Comment: If you happy with my answer please vote on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```js
$('#inputselect').mouseover(function(event){
 $('#inputselect').show();
 $('#inputselect')[0].size= $('#inputselect option').length;
});

$('#inputselect').mouseout(function(event){
 $('#inputselect').show();
 $('#inputselect')[0].size=1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <select name="select" id="inputselect" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the same at [Trigger click on select box on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622191/trigger-click-on-select-box-on-hover) . You need Chosen for this.

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown" data-placeholder="Mouseover">
    <option value="one">Option 1</option>
    <option value="two">Option 2</option>
    <option value="three">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#dropdown").chosen().next(".chosen_container").hover(
    function(){
        $("#dropdown").trigger("liszt:open");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).trigger("click");
    }
);
```

Comment: there is a console error:
"selectOption.php:51 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function"

Comment: You should be voting to close as a duplicate for something which is basically identical

Comment: I am new in this platform, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Phong Thanks. Will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Trader9Hasan That is because the plugin/js has not been added/ added successfully. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024764/plug-in-does-not-load/15025984> check this link, and try to search first, these questions have been answered already.