# Can a <form><select> list be made to drop down on a hover with just HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I'd like to make this form's `select` list automatically drop down on a hover, just like the menu for the "Layout..." button automatically drops down, using only HTML and CSS.  I've tried copying the button's CSS tricks to the option list without success.  Can it be done?

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none; /* don't drop down until time to show */
  position: absolute; /* keep button in-place */
  background-color: white; /* so items aren't see-through */
  border: 1px solid; /* dropdown outline */
}

.dropdown-content a { /* links inside the dropdown */
  text-decoration: none; /* avoid underlining */
  display: block; /* put each link on a line */
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover { background-color: rgb(200,235,255); }

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Layout...</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="small.html">Small</a>
  <a href="medium.html">Medium</a>
  <a href="large.html">Large</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>

<form action="action.dll" method="GET">
  <input class="forminput" type="submit" value="Find:"> <input type="text" name="target" value=""> in 
    <select name="field" id="field">
    <option value = "Field1">Field1</option>
    <option value = "Field2">Field2</option>
    <option value = "Field3">Field3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible using the standard `<select>` element with only CSS. There are JS options like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60407758/7216508) if you must. For accessibility concerns, I wouldn't recommend using `div` and a `button` as in your snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Comment: @blurfus No, those apparently all either no longer work or rely on Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CSS but you can do this by using simple JavaScript.

Here's a example from your code:

```html
<select
      name="field"
      id="field"
      onClick="clicked()"
      onmouseenter="expand(this)"
      onmouseleave="shrink(this)"
    >
      <option value="Field1" onclick="clicked()">Field1</option>
      <option value="Field2" onclick="clicked()">Field2</option>
      <option value="Field3" onclick="clicked()">Field3</option>
    </select>

    <script>
      function expand(obj) {
        obj.size = 3;
      }
      function shrink(obj) {
        obj.size = 1;
      }
      function clicked() {
        obj = document.getElementById("field");
        obj.size = 1;
      }
    </script>
```